# Strange image result for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6, uibarbuttonitem

I want to add the following image to the `UIBarButtonItem`:

[image]

However when I set it to the "Image" property of the `UIBarButtonItem` via Interface Builder in XCode 6 I got the following result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your images get tinted using the tint color and alpha mask.

You can set it to render the original by calling

```
 [myBarButton setImage:[[self imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

on the button!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can I do it via Interface Builder?

Comment: @FrozenHeart Unfortunately you cannot, drop it in `viewDidLoad`